# how to handle a clear textbox event

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, event-handling

I have a `textbox` and a `datetime` picker. What I want to do is when I input the data inside the textbox (the data is retrieved from database), I want to make the datetime picker to be disabled(SOLVED).

My question right now is how to make the `datetime` picker enable when I clear the Greeting `textbox` (using the 'x' to clear the `textbox` as shown in the picture).

[image]

The code for my question:

C#

```
protected void scGreeting_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CriteriaComposite cc = new CriteriaComposite(new Criteria(typeof(Greeting), "PlatNumber", scGreeting.Value));
    cc.And(new Criteria(typeof(Greeting), "Status", 0));
    Greeting greeting = new ServiceFacade(User).SelectList<Greeting>(cc)[0];

    DateTime jamMasuk = Convert.ToDateTime(greeting.CreatedOn);

    //calEnterTimeDate.Text - jamMasuk.Date.ToString();
    calEnterTimeDate.SelectedDate = jamMasuk.Date;
    ddlEnterHour.SelectedValue = jamMasuk.Hour.ToString();
    ddlEnterMinute.SelectedValue = jamMasuk.Minute.ToString();

    calEnterTimeDate.Enabled = false;
    ddlEnterHour.Enabled = false;
    ddlEnterMinute.Enabled = false;
    //scGreeting.TextBoxEnable = false;
}
```

asp.net

```
<td width="25%"><uc1:SearchControl ID="scGreeting"  
                                   runat="server" 
                                   TabIndex="3" 
                                   ReturnType="CodeOnly" 
                                   AutoPostBack="true"
                                   DomainType="Greeting" 
                                   CodeField="PlatNumber" 
                                   TextField="IsBooking" 
                                  OnButtonClicked="scGreeting_ButtonClicked"
                                  Condition="CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 111) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, CreatedOn, 111) AND Status = 0 ORDER BY IsBooking DESC,CreatedOn ASC"/>
</td>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question sort of reads as a set of requirements. Any code to show? What research have you done? These things will help us help you.  Good luck!   _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_